# logcat is showing unexplained libgps errors in Android

Tags: java, android, gps, logcat

While debugging an app I'm making I have these weird logcat errors popping up

```
S/libgps  ( 2674):
S/libgps  ( 2674): SYS : Enter SuplSmIdle event:3
S/libgps  ( 2674):
S/libgps  ( 2674):
S/libgps  ( 2674): CPPLUG : Session handle is NULL in CpPlug_SendEvent
S/libgps  ( 2674):
S/libgps  ( 2674):
S/libgps  ( 2674): SUPLPLUG : SUPL context or session pointer is NULL.
```

also these errors

```
S/libgps  ( 2674): PPOS Error (Time mismatch)! GLN=56791853.000000 GPS=478009450.000000 offset=0
S/libgps  ( 2674):
S/libgps  ( 2674):
S/libgps  ( 2674): PPOS Error (Time mismatch)! GLN=56792053.000000 GPS=478009650.000000 offset=0
S/libgps  ( 2674):
S/libgps  ( 2674):
S/libgps  ( 2674): PPOS Error (Time mismatch)! GLN=56792253.000000 GPS=478009850.000000 offset=0
S/libgps  ( 2674):
```

Can anyone enlighten me what these could possibly mean? I have already done some research but nothing helpful came out of that...

If you need additional information about the app I can provide it. I can't really provide any code because I have no clue which part of the code is the cause of these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the lib wants to do some merge or check from data received by GPS (US-GNSS) and GLONASS (Russian GNSS). It seems that two messages from that different two location sources, have non matching timestamps.
GLN seems to be the abbreviation of GLONASS.

This all is my asumption, as long as you cannot get a better answer.

Comment: Do you know if I can do anything to stop these errors? Or should I not be worried by them? The application keeps working as intended.

Comment: I doubt you can do anything. I would not be worried.